# Never ending "Run configure hook of core snap if present"

Tags: debian, software-installation, snapshot

I am using Debian 9 with KDE Plasma for work and fun, I just wanted to install Krita graphics app. It became an opportunity to tryout new instalation system called "snap". So I installed snapd and called (as root) `/home/user# snap install krita`.

Instead of new program installed I got these messages:

```
2017-08-09T23:47:17+02:00 INFO snap "core" has bad plugs or slots: core-support-plug (unknown interface)
[|] Run configure hook of "core" snap if present
```

And `[|] Run configure hook of "core" snap if present` seems like to run forever :(

How to repair this problem?

Update:

Rerunning `/home/user# snap install krita` gives another problems:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "core" (2462) security profiles (cannot setup seccomp for snap "core": fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap-seccomp: no such file or directory)
- Setup snap "core" (2462) security profiles (fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap-seccomp: no such file or directory)
```

PS: I would file a bug report but... I am really tired of setting up and maintaining another logins/password just to report it. 10 years ago, I could do it, but now it is too much. If a project is not on Github I pass.

Comment: Try as Root.  See [Usage](https://snapcraft.io/docs/core/usage)

Comment: I did it as root, see the `#` before `snap install krita` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1674193) bug report comments snapd is failing if you install core and any snap at the same time.

To avoid the error you have to purge and reinstall snapd:

```
# apt purge snapd
# apt install snapd
```

Install the core snap:

```
# snap install --edge core
```

Install the snap you want, in this case krita:

```
# snap install krita
```

Comment: removing snapd with --purge -- won't that **REMOVE ALL SNAPS**??!

Comment: @etyrnal Yes. But no other way. Even now it is the same situation. Installing Core / Core20 along with applications like firefox, etc is still an issue but with OS installation this happens. We need to completely remove snap (disconnect few services, umount few, stop... and purge), apt install snapd separately, snap install core / core20 separately and then install applications.